# Is it possible to change the orientation of the Input field text insert blinker from vertical to horizontal?

Tags: forms, input, field

I am playing around with the text input field text insert blinker and I've tried a few things but nothing worked to be able to rotate the blinker from vertical state to horizontal state like it looks in the command prompt. I've loaded an image to reference. So I'm wondering if this is even possible to do? Any assistance will be great.

[command prompt sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXgCe.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should try pressing the insert key. If that doesn't work go into your settings by right clicking the DOS icon

Comment: Are you talking about inside the CMD console? I'm trying to do this inside a form field of a web browser. Not the CMD.